# Create & return a list on the fly with Data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I end up creating a lot of business objects for a task as simple as

> returning a list of years from database.

My current approach is to make a year class file then make a `YearCollection:List<year>`class file etc.

> How can I return a list from a DAL method without creating
>   separate class files for each task ?

Comment: Is there any metadata associated to year that you have it as a whole class instead of a primitive type?

Comment: The year is just a distinct column being fetched as a list from database. So I was ending up with a whole lot of new classes for each requirement.

Comment: So if it's a simple integer with no more properties, what Eranga suggested should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a `List<int>` from your DAL method

```
public List<int> GetYears()
{
    var years = new List<int>();

    //create the reader

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        years.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
    }

    return years;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Eranga. Do you advise creating an object class for every operation or I could just create and return objects on the fly as you advised?

Comment: @DamienJoe Depend on situation. `List<int>` maybe ambiguous in some situations as what it holds. For example it maybe a list of years or list of days. Try make the code simple and clear. Creating custom collection types is an overkill.

Comment: Thank you Eranga. What do you say about situations where only 3 or 4 columns are needed from database. Should we follow similar approach ? I am marking your reply as answer.

Comment: @DamienJoe Then it is better to create a Data Transfer Object(DTO) that contains those properties.